# Laravel Proper Relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

So i have a 3 tables. Users-Inventory-Item. User hasmany Items, so far i have no problem. I can reach Items of User with this relationship.

Item table contains : user_id, item_id

So my problem is to reach item info of the Inventory of the User by item_id(which will find id of Item table and bring the info). I couldn't manage it, I need you advices about which relations would be the proper for my aim.

## Models

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function Inventory(){
        return $this->hasMany('App/Item');
    }

class UserItem extends Authenticatable
{
    public function Item(){
        return $this->hasMany('App/Item');
    }
```

## Code in my controller

```
public function profile(){
    $inventory_items = Auth::user()->Inventory;
    return view('profile', compact('inventory_items'));
}
```

So i can get User's items with these code but. When i would like to get item info via this `$inventory_items->item` its not working. I think this is because of  relationship mistakes of mine.

## Codes in Profile

```
@foreach($inventory_items as $inventory_item)

   {{$inventory_item->Item}}<br><br>

@endforeach
```

## Error

> (2/2) ErrorException Class 'App/Item' not found (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\X-GOTL\resources\views\profile.blade.php)

Comment: Can you please add some code to your question, such as what you have already tried and why it didn't work to your expectation. Thanks!

Comment: added now, hope it will make you understand. its something easy to do i guess but i just dont know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is a few errors in your code, no? See my inline comments. Also, you seem to be forgetting that there are many inventories per user and many items per inventory so you need a double-foreach loop.

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{ 
    # There are many inventories per user so put a plural 's' on items
    public function inventories()
    {
        # This should NOT be App\Item

        return $this->hasMany('App\Inventory');
    }
...

# This should NOT be UserItem but Inventory, right? (Remember to rename that file too!)
class Inventory extends Authenticatable
{
    # There are many items per inventory so put a plural 's' on items
    public function items()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Item');
    }
```

Also your error tells you that you have not created a file `App\Item` so run `php artisan make:model Item`.

then in your controller do:

```
public function profile()
{
        $inventories = Auth::user()->inventories;
        return view('profile', compact('inventories'));
}
```

and in your view

```
@foreach($inventories as $inventory)
    @foreach($inventory->items as $item)
        {{ $item->name }} or {{ $item->id }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: I did as you said but now gives error again.. (2/2) ErrorException
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: (2/2) ErrorException
Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\X-GOTL\resources\views\profile.blade.php)

Answer (score 0):

Dev tend to make mistake \ (correct) and / (wrong).. ErrorException Class 'App/Item' show it cant find 'App/Item' which actually wrong syntax

```
 return $this->hasMany('App/Item');
```

change to

```
 return $this->hasMany(Item::class);
```

Comment: what do you mean by this i didnt get it?

Comment: aahh just understood \ / ok.. yea

Answer (score 0):

So guys actually i found the answer i needed. I just needed to create pivot table to make connection between Users and Items. So if someone will have same problem he can watch this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=akKWC_vP7sE . Thanks to you for your answers anyways!